# Is it possible to allocate a dimm slot to a VM

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, security, virtualization

I read that it is possible to escape a VM by overflowing the RAM and sending something in the main OS.

So would it be possible (even in theory) to allocate one of the RAM stick or dimm port to a VM?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machines use emulated hardware from the Virtual Machine App.

The VM hardware is not the Host real hardware.

Accordingly, it is not possible to allocate specific RAM components (sticks) to any Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

NNo, your hypervisor doesn't understand things the way you do.
You can't physically locate where your RAM is being used.